# Linux date: invalid date

Tags: linux, date, gnu

Can someone explain this?  It returns "invalid date" only if the time is at 1 or 2.  After 3am it does do the conversion to unix time stamp.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.

[user@localhost ~]$ date --date="Sun Mar 10 01:59:00 PDT 2013" +%s
date: invalid date `Sun Mar 10 01:59:00 PDT 2013'

[user@localhost ~]$ date --date="Sun Mar 10 02:59:00 PDT 2013" +%s
date: invalid date `Sun Mar 10 02:59:00 PDT 2013'

[user@localhost ~]$ date --date="Sun Mar 10 03:59:00 PDT 2013" +%s
1362913140

[user@localhost ~]$ date --date="Sun Mar 10 04:59:00 PDT 2013" +%s
1362916740
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Daylight saving started in the US on 10th March 2013 when the clocks moved forward to 3am. Your time zone is PDT - i.e. Pacific **Daylight Saving** Time, only valid from 3am that day. Earlier than that the time zone was PST - Pacific **Standard** Time, which finished at 2am.

Comment: @rici Typo on my part. Should be Standard...